# edit admin template varibles global variables via cms

Tags: control-panel, admin, global-variables

how do i edit preferences for global variables in the cms, design > templates > global variables.

Iv looked at the following and think it might be what i'm looking to do, wondering if the cms cant do this without adding a module?

What i want to edit specifically is allowing variables to be left blank and when they are blank to not display the content "image" associated with the variable. (this i can look at as it will be an if statement) but the settings i cant seem to figure out.

was avoiding the use of a module regarding this issue but i have found one which might be able to give me this option:

http://republiclabs.com/expressionengine/republic-variables

Answer (score 1):

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables may be your answer, that will all you mention plus a whole lot more.